# Delete a character array in VC++

Tags: c++

I have the following code. When I try to delete the pDest, error occurs. How can I delete pDest. Is there any other operation need to delete this?

```
{
    int nReqLen = nSrcLength;
    char* pDest = new char[nReqLen+1];
        .
        .
        .
        .
    memcpy( (char*)pSource, pDest, nSrcLength );
    delete pDest;
    return nReturn;
}
```

Comment: It is a runtime error, and the error message in the messagebox is "an unhandled exception at ....."

Comment: `memcpy` is `memcpy(destination, source, size)`...if we knew *what* "error occurs," we could point you in the right direction.

Comment: pSource and pDest are of same size

Comment: Can you post the whole error message from the message box? The part after your truncation is the important part.

Comment: Unhandled Exception at 0x7c901230 in SmartTracker.exe : User breakpoint

Comment: This is the full code :-  int CAes::Encrypt(unsigned char* pSource, int nSrcLength)
{
 int nReqLen = nSrcLength;

 char* pDest = new char[nReqLen + 1]; 
 int nReturn = my_aes_encrypt( (char*)pSource, nSrcLength, pDest, (char*)m_pKey, m_nKeySize );
 
 memcpy( (char*)pSource, pDest, nSrcLength );

 delete pDest;
 return nReturn;
}                                                                       //if the pDest is declared as                                    //char* pDest = new char[nReqLen + 16];   then there is no error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to say `delete[] pDest`.  It was allocated as an array so it needs to be deleted as an array.

Comment: I already try to delete using this "delete [] pDest;" but the same runtime error occured.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [] in the delete

`delete [] pDest;` since it is an array

Comment: I already try to delete using this "delete [] pDest;" but the same runtime error occured

Answer (score 0):

```
delete pDest;
```

It invokes undefined behavior, because `pDest` is allocated memory using `new T[N]` form.

If you use `new T[]` syntax, then you've to write `delete []t` syntax.

If `T` is typdef of `U[N]` and you write `new T`, even then you've to use `delete []t`. For example,

```
typedef int IntArr[100];

int *pint = new IntArr; //See it is not of the form of new T[N];

//delete pint; //wrong
delete [] pint; //correct
```